# How to get H1 content the same height in Firefox and in IE8?

Tags: html, css

I have the following simple page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .img {background:green; width:32px; height:32px;}
        h1.imgHdr        {font-size:18px; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal; color:#1E395B; font-family:Arial;}
        h1.imgHdr>span   {display:block; float:left; margin-right:5px;}
        h1.imgHdr span.t {margin-top:11px; width:200px;}
        div.line         {height:1px; margin:0; padding:0; background:#aaa;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="line"></div>
<h1 class="imgHdr">
        <span class="img"></span>
        <span class="t" style="width:auto">Documents</span>
        <a style="clear:both;display:block"></a>
</h1>
<div class="line"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

In IE8 I get the behavior I'm looking for. The 2 grey divs are flush against the green square.

But in Firefox 3.6.8 I get an extra pixel of space before the bottom div line. I can't figure out why, or how to change the CSS to make FF and IE do the same thing for this markup.

I think it has to do with the spans inside of the h1.

I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Even after adding a link to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.1.2/build/cssreset/reset-context-min.css">
```

...the problem persists.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it helpful to explicitly set the `line-height`. With the `line-height` set to the same value as `font-size`, you get vertically centered text that occupies as much height as you expect. I'm not positive that this helps in your particular case, but give it a shot. I recommend trying it in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Hmm even w/ line-height:18px; I have the same behavior :(

Comment: I'm on FF3.6.8 as well, and it looks fine to me in the above URL. No extra pixel.

Comment: I'm sorry! You are right. I've got some caching problem w/ my dev web server. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [YUI Reset CSS library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/) was created for this very problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting defaults for the elements doesn't seem to correct this particular problem.